# Unable to trigger Tap Gesture Identifier for 2 Images on the same View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have assigned 2 different tap gesture identifiers to my 2 images in my View Controller. I want access and assign them different images when tapped. I have written the following code and it works only for one image. But, I am not sure how can assign it to two different images. I have even assigned the two images different tags, but, not sure how to use them. Any help will highly appreciated! Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class EleventhViewController: UIViewController { 

@IBOutlet weak var person1ImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var person2ImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    person1ImageView.tag = 1
    person2ImageView.tag = 2

}

extension EleventhViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

//This is the tap gesture added on my UIImageView.

@IBAction func didTapOnImageView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //call Alert function
    self.showAlert()
}

//Show alert to selected the media source type.
private func showAlert() {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Selection", message: "From where you want to pick this image?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
        self.getImage(fromSourceType: .camera)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Album", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
        self.getImage(fromSourceType: .photoLibrary)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//get image from source type
private func getImage(fromSourceType sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {

    //Check is source type available
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) {

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//MARK:- UIImagePickerViewDelegate.
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in

        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        //Setting image to your image view
        
        self?.person2ImageView.image = image
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` object for every imageView  and add it , if you  added the same 1 to both images it will trigger only for the last 1

```
 var last = 0
 @objc func didTapOnImageView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
    last = sender.view!.tag
 }
```

Comment: Yes! I have added another function for another Tap gesture recognizer for 2nd image

Comment: But, what about in the imagePickerControlle function? How shall I assign the image? Does it have too be in the same function? Lie this self?.person1ImageView.image = image

Comment: yes like what you did , if you need to differentiate which imageview clicked inside the gesture function save a variable of the last clicked tag and check it in side `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo `

Comment: Thanks! But, I am not sure how to check the tag for an imageView. Could you pleased help me with that

Comment: if (imageView.tag == 2) {
                
                self?.person2ImageView.image = image
                
            }
            else {
                
                self?.person1ImageView.image = image
                
            }

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: store `last`  as in edit and check it's value against `self.imageView1` or `imageView2` tags inside `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo `